# Join in Google BigQuery via Cloud Datalab

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to do JOIN on two columns from two different tables (one of them is a view) in Google BigQuery. I have tried this numerous ways, but have received this error the most consistently:

```
invalidQuery: 2.1 - 0.0: JOIN cannot be applied directly to a table union or to a table wildcard function. Consider wrapping the table union or table wildcard function in a subquery (e.g., SELECT *).
```

Here is my SQL (legacy) query:

```
SELECT 
  blp_today.beta_key,
  blp_today.px_last,
  blp_today.eqy_weighted_avg_px,
  blp_today.created_date,
  blp_today.security_ticker,
  ciq_company_stg.ticker,
  ciq_company_stg.ciq
FROM 
  [fcm-dw:acquisition_bloomberg.blp_today],
  [fcm-dw:acquisition_ciq] 
JOIN
  blp_today.security_ticker AS ticker
ON
  blp_today.security_ticker = ciq_company_stg.ticker
LIMIT 1000
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you either want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT 
  beta_key,
  px_last,
  eqy_weighted_avg_px,
  created_date,
  security_ticker,
FROM 
  [fcm-dw:acquisition_bloomberg.blp_today],
  [fcm-dw:acquisition_ciq] ) as  a
JOIN
  blp_today.security_ticker AS ticker
ON
  a.security_ticker = ciq_company_stg.ticker
LIMIT 1000
```

//edit: I kind of missed earlier that the table that you are joining (after your join statement) does not actually seem to be a table. Are you trying to join or to union these two tables: [fcm-dw:acquisition_bloomberg.blp_today] and  [fcm-dw:acquisition_ciq] ? And is the latter even a table? Your code seems to indicate that there is another table named: [fcm-dw:acquisition_ciq.ciq_company_stg]?

Comment: The latter is actually a view of the same table, this helped though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First wrap your union into a sub select then join the result

```
select ...
FROM 
(select * from 
  [fcm-dw:acquisition_bloomberg.blp_today],
  [fcm-dw:acquisition_ciq] ) t
JOIN
  blp_today.security_ticker AS ticker
```